# Sql output based on the given table data

Tags: sql

Hi I have a table as shown below

```
Col1    Col2
A.      10
B.      20 
C.      30 
D.      80
E.      50
```

Output should be

```
Col1.          Col2 
A,B,C,D,E.     190
```

That is first column values should be separated by comma and second column values needs to be summed up

Please suggest a sql query for this scenario

Comment: what RDBMS you are using?

Comment: I want queries in both Oracle and Microsoft sql

Comment: @SudarshanHR, you can't find a query for this that works with both Oracle and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

> I think you are looking for this one ??
>
> instead of listtagg use string_agg for sql server

```
SELECT  LISTAGG(col1, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1 ) AS 
employees,sum(col2)
FROM   your_table_name
GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: LISTAGG is for oracle ?

Comment: Actually this is the correct query .  SELECT  LISTAGG(col1, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1 ) AS 
employees,sum(col2)
FROM   your_table_name .    If you do group by at the last , it will group the employee name and will give output just like the input .

Answer (score 0):

Check the below solution for MS SQL.

```
SELECT (REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [Col1] FROM your_table_name FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), '.,',',')) AS [Col1],
Sum(Col2) as col2
FROM your_table_name
```

Comment: @jarlh, will you please check it in MS SQL and not in mySQL. I edit my comment!! Thanks, It works in it